# using where clause in ObservableCollection

Tags: .net, observablecollection

```
   private ObservableCollection<OrganizationUnit> _Organizations = new ObservableCollection<OrganizationUnit>();
   private ObservableCollection<OrganizationUnit> _OrganizationManagement;

_OrganizationManagement = new ObservableCollection<OrganizationUnit>(_Organizations.Where(p => p.Type == "DealerGroup").ToList());
            GridOrganizationManagement.ItemsSource = _OrganizationManagement;
```

I have main list `_Organizations` I want that `_OrganizationManagement` contains filter list of "DealerGroup".

But problem is using above _Organizations and _OrganizationManagement are not sync when after this code I add value in _Organizations it doesnot add in _OrganizationManagement what i have understand we are filtering it with `new ObservableCollection` so new instance is pass to _OrganizationManagement

Comment: See: [Bindable LINQ](http://bindablelinq.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to subscribe to the CollectionChanged event of _Organizations and refresh _OrganizationManagement. To preserve the bindings use something like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<OrganizationUnit> _Organizations = new ObservableCollection<OrganizationUnit>();
private ObservableCollection<OrganizationUnit> _OrganizationManagement;

GridOrganizationManagement.ItemsSource = _OrganizationManagement;

_Organisations.CollectionChanged += (s,e) =>
{
    var newlist = new ObservableCollection<OrganizationUnit>(_Organizations.Where(p => p.Type == "DealerGroup").ToList());
    _OrganizationManagement.Clear();
    foreach(var o in newlist)
        _OrganizationManagement.Add(o);
}
```

Comment: You're better off using the NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e and iterating over e.NewItems so that you don't get  ConcurrentModificationExceptions. You're quite right that this will work though.